# how to calculate circle radius depending on zoom google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have drawn the circle using google.maps.Circle and now I need to calculate it's radius depending on current zoom. For example if my current zoom is 2 my rad is 100000 if current zoom is 21 rad is 1. I'm bad in math so how can I calculate it for other zoom levels?

Answer (score -1):

`getRadius()` does not give you the result you need?

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle

Comment: I need dynamicly change setRadius() wich will depend on zoom, to see circle in all zoom levels like marker

Comment: @РоманМальцев Hey, i also got the same problem with yours, did you manage to solve and if yes how did you solve it? Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely not what the user was asking for. The user was asking for a way of setting the radius property of the circle, based on the zoom level. Given that Google Maps uses radius in meters, this property should change based on the zoom level